# MySQL query works fine in AWS lightsail MySQL db but not working in RDS MySQL aurora

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I have a nested Query something like below:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT account WHERE (account LIKE '123456%')) as account_no
FROM table
WHERE type=1
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

It is working fine in MySQL DB. But it shows Error Code 1046 in AWS RDS MySQL Aurora. But why?

It shows error near

```
"WHERE (account LIKE '123456%')"
```

Is there any alternative way to achieve the goal? I have searched this error for Aurora but can't find a solution.

Comment: You're missing a `FROM` clause in your subquery...

Comment: I am also used that but same error. This same query working on other MySQL DB.

Comment: Error 1046 is "No database selected". If you don't qualify all the table names with the database name, you need to select a default database with `USE databasename`

Comment: RDS is connected with MySQL workbench ... And I have selected db using db_name.table_name. And I am not getting the error you are mentioned here. @Barmar

Comment: But that's what that error code means.

Comment: My Error Response - 

`Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (account LIKE '123456%' OR account LIKE ' at line 1`

Comment: Regardless of what works/doesn't work on the other database, what do you actually want the query to do? From which table do you want it to retrieve the `account`? And what do you want the whole query to do? It doesn't seem to be making much sense at the moment. Is it saying "return me the a row where `type=1`, with the lowest ID and show an `account` from <somewhere>".

Comment: Ok let me share the schema with you. Give me a moment please.